# How to horizontally align irregularly shaped point symbol to vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, point, symbology

Fairly new to QGIS and searching a method to graphically align my point symbols in the direction of the vector. The symbol represents a water valve in an irregular shape in close proximity to a vector water network--is there a way to align each symbol adjacent/ horizontal to a water network vector layer?

Answer (score 6):

<s>Yes, but it's a manual method I read about.</s>

In QGIS 2.0.1 you can set the point symbol to be rotated based on an angle(integer/double) in a field.

Have a look at [What is the best way to represent bridges using a point vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20667/1297)

In that example, "bridges" which are represented as point features and with a custom symbol on the map are rotated based on a value in a field.

#### **Getting Your Bearings** *(automatic method)*

This is basically a spatial join from a line attribute *(the bearing)* to the nearest point feature.

[image: lines and points in the flesh]

**1.)** Split line feature into segments based on nodes/vertices with **v.split.vert** in the processing toolbox (**GRASS** required):

[image: v.split.vert - splitting based on "2" vertices per segment]

**2.)** Use [QGIS field calculator on split_lines to get the bearing for each segment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24364/1297) (start editing layer before field calculator can be used):

For convenience: `(atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))`

[image: qgis field calculator used to get bearing of a line segment]
Stop editing and save changes to retain your newly created `[bearing]` field.

**3.)** Use **Distance to nearest hub** in the *Processing* toolbox and set the split_lines as the **Destination Hubs Layer** with `[bearing]` in the **Hub Layer Name Attribute**. *Measurement Unit can safely be ignored in this example.*

[image: Using "Distance to nearest hub" to attach attribute from lines to points in QGIS]

**4.)** Create a new *Decimal Number* type field in the points_with_bearings file called `[bearing]` to convert the `[HubName]` field from a string. *`[HubName]` and `[HubDist]` can be deleted if they're not needed.*

Stop editing points_with_bearings and save changes.

[image: qgis field calculator]

**5.)** Go to the **Style** tab in the *Layer Properties* window for the points_with_bearings layer and set `[bearing]` as the *Rotation Field*.

[image: setting a point rotation value based on a field in QGIS]

[image: rotated points aligned with nearest line segment rendered in QGIS]

References:

- [Join attributes of point and line layer by location (closest
  distance) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15790/1297)
- [How to add Direction and Distance to attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24364/1297)