# How can I create individual directional point symbols in MapInfo?

Tags: symbology, mapinfo, direction

I have a point tab file where one of the attributes is a 0-360 direction. I want to create an arrow symbol for  each point with the arrow pointing in the direction listed for that point in the table. Is this possible? I'm using MapInfo but would welcome a solution in ArcMap or QGIS also.

Comment: Thank you! Does anyone know how to do this same thing in MapInfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MapInfo there is a tool called Rotate Symbols under the Tools menu. This will allow you to rotate symbols based on a fixed value or an attribute value in a specific column. There is a [tutorial available here](http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-may-2014/Toolbox-Rotating-Symbols/?webSyncID=1ab42f19-1fc7-4272-a0ba-e03751ebc3fe&vs=Y2Q0YTcwMGItOTU1My00MWI0LWE4YjgtYjY5ZTNmODk1MDRmOzsS1) with detailed instructions.

Within ArcMap this can be done on the symbology tab of the point layer properties, using Rotation under the Advanced dropdown button. See the [help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001v000000) for detailed info.

There is a similar dialog in QGIS - Layer Properties > Style tab > Advanced > Rotation tab. See [How to horizontally align irregularly shaped point symbol to vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/) and in particular Step 5 of the answer and its accompanying graphic. Also the [QGIS documentation (for 2.6)](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html) (under figure 1).