# Align arrow (point layer) to water direction (line feature)

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, vector, flow

Assuming that pipes are digitizet correctly (first node as upstream, last as downstream), I need to align the arrows of a point layer to display flowmeter's direction. So far I need to use v.split (GRASS), then populate a new field with this expression (see [How to horizontally align irregularly shaped point symbol to vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/how-to-horizontally-align-irregularly-shaped-point-symbol-to-vector-layer-in-qgi)):

```
(atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)- yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))
```

and then this angle can be assigned to nearest point with refFunctions plugin:

```
geomdistance('pipes', 'Angle', 0.001)
```

Since the flowmeters will be moved to different pipes, I'm looking for a different procedure that will change automatically the angle, I'm open to advices.
What comes to my mind is:

1. buffer a circumference (radious like 5 meters) around each point,
2. select the segment inside buffer
3. apply the angle formula to this segment and then write the value as point attribute

Questions are: can it be done? Suggestions in how to do it (preferably with field calculator)?